# Redux useSelector shows Unresolved variable warning in intelliJ/webSotrm

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, redux, webstorm

I'm wondering about others approach to Redux useSelector hook. For example in my code:

`const selectedStage = useSelector(state => state.basket.stage);`

IntelliJ/WebStorm are giving me warning *Unresolved variable basket*
I see two options: turning off this warning or use destructuring like:

`const { basket: { stage: selectedStage} } = useSelector(state => state);`

I think it is much less readable. Is there anything I miss or could be done better?

------- EDIT ---------

If I simplify my Redux setup to basic like:

```
const basketReducer = (state = initialState.basket, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case CHANGE_BASKET_SETTINGS:
            return { ...state, ...action.payload };
...
```

```
export default combineReducers({
    basket: basketReducer,
...
```

```
import allReducers from "../reducers";
export const store = createStore(allReducers);
```

I get same warning. It's really annoying.

Comment: What does your app's store/reducer setup look like? How are you defining the root reducer?  And yes, you should _never_ write a selector that is `state => state` - you should always [return the smallest piece of data this component needs](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-5-ui-react#using-multiple-selectors-in-a-component).

Comment: Also, it looks similar to this known issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-50731

Comment: @markerikson my app is rather old and has some custom changes but I simplified it to basic setup and I updated in my question.

Comment: yeah, my first guess is this is a WebStorm-specific issue. I bet if you opened that same file in VS Code it will display correctly.